# How to use LIKE in oracle with PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, oracle

I am trying to use a simple SQL statment with the LIKE operator. This SQL statement works on SQL developer but not when I try it on PHP.

```
SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%luxury%';
```

However when I do the same thing in php I get this error:

> Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

PHP Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%:term%'";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$term = "luxury";
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":term", $term);
oci_execute($stid);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to concatenate the string parts with the parameter, like :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE lower(name) = '%' || :term || '%'";
```

NB: do you really want to search for a string surrounded by *litteral* `'%'`s? Given the title of the question, you might be looking for the `LIKE` operator instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%' || :term || '%'";
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. Sorry, I made a typo in the question. Fixed the OP

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't allow me to select it as the answer (need to wait 6 minutes). But I will select it once I can

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a bind parameter inside of a SQL literal string (''). You can use `LIKE '%' || :term || '%'";` as shown in the other answer, or you can append `%` in your PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE lower(name) LIKE :term";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$term = "%" . "luxury" . "%";
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":term", $term);
oci_execute($stid);
```